# Full Read/Control on whole SharePoint Online Tenant

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is it possible to grant full control or full read permissions to a user account of a SharePoint Online Tenant?

Answer (score 0):

In the SharePoint admin center->site collection->owner, we can add users as site collection administrators who have full control to the relevant site collection.

In the SharePoint site->site settings->site permissions, we can grant the users with relevant permission levels such as full control, read.

Reference: [Understanding permission levels in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Understanding-permission-levels-in-SharePoint-87ecbb0e-6550-491a-8826-c075e4859848?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: I know that this is possible. But I would like to know if it's possible to grant Full Control permissions to the complete SharePoint Online Tenant (e.g. on all Site Collections etc.)
Just like on OnPremise environments where I can control the access permissions of a whole Web Application.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide permissions to following groups :

1. All Authenticated Users: All user accounts which can be recognized by SharePoint Online, both for internal and external.
2. All Users (Windows) : User accounts from Federated domains.
   [image]
3. All Users (membership): All user accounts from Office 365 Online Services.

`To add to this, there's also 'Everyone' and 'Everyone except external users'`

**Or In some cases `Everyone` also works**

`Everyone` was what worked for me

***EDIT***
Everyone is a default group that contains all authenticated and guest users that can connect to your network.

[image]